Trying to combine 3 different tables with different selected columns
I am trying to combine the following tables based on these commonalities.
I first JOINED these tables:
SELECT TOP 5
    vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID,
    vFlatShareBalance.RelationshipEstablishDate,
    vFlatSoftPull.EstimatedIncome
FROM 
    [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatShareBalance]
INNER JOIN 
    [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatSoftPull]
         ON vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID = vFlatSoftPull.EnterpriseCustomerID




EnterpriseCustomerID
RelationshipEstablishDate
EstimatedIncome




Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A


Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B



Say this is NEW_TABLE, and I want the result to be JOINED with:
    NEW_TABLE.EnterpriseCustomerID,
    vFlatServicingAction.LGD_Rating,
    vFlatServicingAction.PD_Rating
FROM 
    NEW_TABLE
INNER JOIN 
    [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatServicingAction]
        ON vFlatServicingAction.EnterpriseCustomerID = NEW_TABLE.EnterpriseCustomerID




EnterpriseCustomerID
RelationshipEstablishDate
EstimatedIncome
LGD Rating
PD Rating




Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A
Info on Customer A


Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B
Info on Customer B



How do I do it? I've tried WITH tablename AS and CREATE TABLE but it didn't work.
I am able to create the first table. But I don't know how to combine between the new table I've created and the third table.

TOP 5 but no ORDER BY will give you 5 more or less arbitrary rows. Does it matter?

You have very strange sample table data, which makes it very hard to understand what you want. Make it easy to assist you, make up some better sample data.'

It seems you want to add the INNER JOIN from the second snippet to the first query as well as the additional columns.

Use a subquery or a CTE (if needed)

CREATE TABLE [vFlatShareBalance] (
    EnterpriseCustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RelationshipEstablishDate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE [vFlatSoftPull] (
    EnterpriseCustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EstimatedIncome DECIMAL(18, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE [vFlatServicingAction] (
    EnterpriseCustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    LGD_Rating DECIMAL(5, 2),
    PD_Rating DECIMAL(5, 2)
);


INSERT INTO [vFlatShareBalance] (EnterpriseCustomerID, RelationshipEstablishDate)
VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01'),
(2, '2021-02-01'),
(3, '2019-03-15');

INSERT INTO [vFlatSoftPull] (EnterpriseCustomerID, EstimatedIncome)
VALUES
(1, 55000.00),
(2, 62000.00),
(3, 47000.00);

INSERT INTO [vFlatServicingAction] (EnterpriseCustomerID, LGD_Rating, PD_Rating)
VALUES
(1, 1.5, 0.02),
(2, 2.0, 0.05),
(3, 1.2, 0.01);


SELECT TOP 5
    nt.EnterpriseCustomerID,
    nt.RelationshipEstablishDate,
    nt.EstimatedIncome,
    vFlatServicingAction.LGD_Rating,
    vFlatServicingAction.PD_Rating
FROM (
    SELECT 
        vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID,
        vFlatShareBalance.RelationshipEstablishDate,
        vFlatSoftPull.EstimatedIncome
    FROM [vFlatShareBalance]
    INNER JOIN [vFlatSoftPull]
        ON vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID = vFlatSoftPull.EnterpriseCustomerID
) AS nt
INNER JOIN [vFlatServicingAction]
    ON vFlatServicingAction.EnterpriseCustomerID = nt.EnterpriseCustomerID;





EnterpriseCustomerID
RelationshipEstablishDate
EstimatedIncome
LGD_Rating
PD_Rating




1
2020-01-01
55000.00
1.50
0.02


2
2021-02-01
62000.00
2.00
0.05


3
2019-03-15
47000.00
1.20
0.01



fiddle

Could it be you are missing the top 5 in your answer ?

Answer updated thank you

Thank you, Amira ! I should mention that the tables I'm joining already exist. I'm not creating them from scratch.

I just created them to simulate the result of the query.so if my answer helped you don't forget to validate it :)

@Amira already gave you a very good answer. I'll add an alternative syntax, using WITH (a CTE, "common table expression").
WITH NEW_TABLE (EnterpriseCustomerID, RelationshipEstablishDate, EstimatedIncome)
AS
(
  SELECT TOP 5
      vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID,
      vFlatShareBalance.RelationshipEstablishDate,
      vFlatSoftPull.EstimatedIncome
    FROM [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatShareBalance]
    INNER JOIN [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatSoftPull]
      ON vFlatShareBalance.EnterpriseCustomerID = vFlatSoftPull.EnterpriseCustomerID
)       
SELECT NEW_TABLE.*,
  vFlatServicingAction.LGD_Rating,
  vFlatServicingAction.PD_Rating
  FROM NEW_TABLE
  INNER JOIN [DWH_RPT].[dw].[vFlatServicingAction]
    ON vFlatServicingAction.EnterpriseCustomerID = NEW_TABLE.EnterpriseCustomerID;

An extra note: the cardinality (the number of resulting rows) will grow according to how many rows match the "ON" clause in each table (or CTE expression). If, for a for a given EnterpriseCustomerID, you have N rows in NEW_TABLE and M rows in vFlatServicingAction, you'll end up with N x M rows.
